# Mocha, Chai and Sequelize clean and setup data in beforeEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sequelize.js

Mocha, Chai and Sequelize clean and setup data in beforeEach

I want to be able to recreate the needed context for each test.

I wrote this

```
"use strict";
import chai from 'chai';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import chaiExclude from 'chai-exclude';
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../../../utils/databaseMock';

chai.use(chaiExclude);

global.sequelize = sequelize;

const User = sequelize.import('../../../../../src/sequelize/models/user');

describe('users', function(){
  this.timeout(5000); 

  beforeEach(async function() {
    await sequelize.sync();
    return true;
  });

  beforeEach(async function() {
    await User.destroy({
      where: {}
    }).then(function(msg) {
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('err =====================> ', err);
    });
    await User.bulkCreate([
      { id: 1, isDeleted: false, firstName: 'firstName1', lastName: 'lastName1', email: 'email1@test.com', password: 'hashedpass1', createdAt: '2017-10-09 10:57:26', updatedAt: '2019-03-09 09:59:13', isActive: true, isAdministrator: true, birth: null, gender: null, avatarUrl: null, verificationCode: null },
      { id: 2, isDeleted: false, firstName: 'firstName2', lastName: 'lastName2', email: 'email2@test.com', password: 'hashedpass2', createdAt: '2017-10-09 10:57:26', updatedAt: '2018-06-27 09:36:18', isActive: true, isAdministrator: true, birth: null, gender: null, avatarUrl: null, verificationCode: null },
      { id: 3, isDeleted: false, firstName: 'firstName3', lastName: 'lastName3', email: 'email3@test.com', password: 'hashedpass3', createdAt: '2017-10-09 10:57:26', updatedAt: '2017-10-09 11:01:04', isActive: true, isAdministrator: true, birth: null, gender: null, avatarUrl: null, verificationCode: null }
    ]).then(function(msg) {
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('err =====================> ', err);
    });
  });

  it('should find user by id', async () => {
    const retrievedUser = await User.findByPk(2);
    expect(retrievedUser.dataValues).to.deep.equal('it should break');
  });
```

I get two errors

```
parent: [Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed] {
    errno: 19,
    code: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT',
    sql: 'DELETE FROM `Users`'
  },
```

and

```
parent: [Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: UNIQUE constraint failed: Users.id] {
  errno: 19,
  code: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT',
  sql: "INSERT INTO `Users` (`id`,`email`,`password`,`firstName`,`lastName`,`
  ...
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: Do not specify the `id` while doing the `bulkCreate`.

Comment: Thank you @RatulSharker, you help me to realize that the conflict were due the ids. Also in this scheme I should not look up for the id, since it would be changing.